# Forgot mysql root password

Tags: mysql

I forgot mysql root password. How can I get it again? I am trying to use `mysql -u root` command but I am getting this error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Try with `-p` option; then it will prompt you for password. In your case, it's saying that you can't access with user root with no password.

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

In case, you have really forgot your password then take a look here on how to reset the same

[How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) (for 5.7 version)

Comment: I followed your link. here is what I did `Zafars-MacBook-Pro:mysql zafarsaleem$ kill 'cat /usr/local/var/mysql/Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local.pid'
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:mysql zafarsaleem$ mysqld_safe --init-file=/Users/zafarsaleem/mysql-init &`. then I got this output `[1] 58245
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:mysql zafarsaleem$ 120604 13:44:02 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
120604 13:44:02 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists`

Comment: Ruh this command `ps -ef|grep -i mysql` and see whether really a mysql daemon process running or not.

Comment: Zafars-MacBook-Pro:mysql zafarsaleem$ ps -ef|grep -i mysql
  501 58635   205   0  1:57PM ??         0:00.01 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --max_allowed_packet=32M
  501 58695 58635   0  1:57PM ??         0:00.09 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/lib/plugin --max-allowed-packet=32M --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
  501 58763 54292   0  1:58PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i mysql

Comment: Try starting and stopping your `mysql` service and see if works.

Comment: I use mysql.server start|stop command and it works

Comment: It does not work I am still not able to login as root with the password

Comment: Show me the command you are trying.

Comment: Zafars-MacBook-Pro:mysql zafarsaleem$ mysql -u root -h localhost -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: And you are providing the password you newly generated when prompted ... correct?

Comment: yes I am providing the password

Comment: Now that .pid file is deleted from that location